# filter the elements in object array corresponding to value

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
let arr={tp:1, op:1, lp:0, co:0}
```

I want to push the element into a new array whose values is 1
Expected arr is like `{tp,op}`

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object.  Can you show what you've attempted and indicate what specifically isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an object that is more like an "associated array" (i.e. a map).

If you want to get names (keys) which value is 1. You can use the following code:

1. Convert to an array of entries
2. Filter by value
3. Extract name

```js
let arr={tp:1, op:1, lp:0, co:0}

const ones = Object.entries(arr)
  .filter(([_, value]) => value === 1)
  .map(([name]) => name)

console.log(ones)
```

Comment: And if the OP actually wants `{ tp: 1, op: 1 }` then you can use `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr).filter(obj => obj[1] == 1))`

Answer (score 0):

That's an object. [Iterate over the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) and push the property key into an array if its corresponding value equals 1.

```js
const obj = { tp: 1, op: 1, lp: 0, co: 0 };

const arr = [];

for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] === 1) arr.push(key);
}

console.log(arr);
```